# MYSQL: display multiple columns in 1

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4
FROM table
WHERE ...
```

So the result is like:

`col1    col2    col3    col4
 1       2       3       4
 1.1     2.1     3.1     4.1`

But i want a result like:

`col1,col2,col3,col4
 1
 1.1
 2
 2.1
...`

any idea?

edit:
I have to search for a String in 2 tables containing 9 and 1 column(s).
Then i need to sort it all IN 1 COLUMN and only get the 5 first items.

Comment: Your title says 2 columns in 1, but you've got 4 columns of data. Can you edit to clarify?  Also, what "brand" of SQL are you using?  That will determine some capabilities for reorganizing the results.

Comment: Looks to me more like you are exporting a table to a csv? What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: I have to search for a String in 2 tables containing 9 and 1 column(s). Then i need to sort it all IN 1 COLUMN and only get the 5 first items.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using union clause. Somthing like this:-

```
SELECT col1
FROM table
WHERE ...
     UNION
SELECT col2
FROM table
WHERE ...
     UNION
SELECT col3
FROM table
WHERE ...
     UNION
SELECT col4
FROM table
WHERE ...
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If is here no more requirements you could do like this:

```
select first_col
from
 (
   select 'col1, col2, col3, col4' as first_col, 1 as rnk
   union all
   select col1,2
   union all
   select col2,3
   union all
   select col3,4
   union all 
   select col4,5
   ) t
   order by 2
```

Here is an order, but probably you don't need it